# Configuring Angularjs-express app for dev and production failing

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku

My dev box is my local machine. The angularjs front-end makes api calls to the express backend and for this I store the api route and other details in a configuration file :

```
'use strict';
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

if (env === 'development') {

  exports.serverPort = 3000;
  exports.baseUrl = 'http://localhost';
  exports.apiPath = 'http://localhost:3000/';
  ...//database path
  .... // secret key etc
  ....

} else {

  exports.serverPort = process.env.PORT;
  exports.baseUrl = 'https://secret-ef-12.herokuapp.com';
  exports.apiPath = 'https://secret-ef-12.herokuapp.com:' + process.env.PORT + '/';
  ....    
}
```

my dev box has NODE_ENV set to 'development'.

On my heroku account, i have NODE_ENV set to 'production'.

Things work fine on dev machine. However on the heroku account (which is the production machine), the application fails to pickup production values.

please note that after deploying to Heroku I am rebuilding the code using my gulpfile.

```
 //a snippet from package.json 
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/server.js",
    "postinstall": "node node_modules/.bin/gulp build"
  },
```

To reiterate:
After 'git push heroku master', heroku rebuilds my application. No errors are reported.
The angularjs application opens fine when executing 'heroku open'. However all database calls that the application makes go to

```
http://localhost:3000
```

instead of using production values.

I do not understand why the angularJs application on the heroku platform does not pickup production values.

Comment: So if you're rebuilding the code after deploying... what does it look like? Is the code above pre- or post- build? Do you get the `development` settings or an error? We need more info to solve this one.

Comment: Updated the question with the answers

Comment: This may come down to how the `NODE_ENV` variable is being set on the Heroku machine. Environment variables are specific to the shell profile being used for a process, which may be different when you ssh in versus when the Node app is run. Can you add a debug statement in your Node application to simply log the value of `process.env.NODE_ENV` at the top? My guess is that it isn't being set correctly (versus there being something wrong with your Node app).

Comment: very early on I executed 'heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production'.  wasn't aware that NODE_ENV values differ from shell to shell. This is unlikely

Comment: Adding a log statement will tell you for sure. But according to the code you have above, that environment variable is set to `"development"`. So it looks like the issue is with your Heroku setup, not your Node code.

Comment: I added log statements to my angularJs apps.. it outputs development paths. When I hardcoded production paths and uploaded to heroku.. everything worked fine. so at this point I am unsure how to setup a flexible system

Comment: My guess is that the Node application on your Heroku machine is being run under a different user/process/shell than when you do `heroku config:set ...` But I'm not sure how that's happening unless you're executing your Node app in some weird way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually found the issue and solution. Browserify does not read node environment variables. Hence the code above would always return 'development'.

I configured my build file (Gulpfile.js) to generate a development or production build as per a flag passed to it.

What this meant was that my build file (Gulpfile.js) was not searching the environment to tell it whether it should build for dev or prod.

my gulp file is now configured as

gulp build --dev

or

gulp build --production

After deploying code to Heroku, i placed the following line in package.json

```
  "postinstall": "node node_modules/.bin/gulp build --production"
```

For now this is working for me. It also keeps things simple which i prefer.